# MSSQL Filter results by conditions

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables customer and box

```
  customer                       box
name   type   years          type   color   id
=====  =====  =====          =====  =====  =====                    
Tom      30   2019            10    red      1
Jame     10   2020            10    black    2
Abby     20   2020            20    green    3
Tad      20   2018            20    blue     4
```

i query by this

```
SELECT * FROM customer inner join box on customer.type = box.type WHERE years = '2020'
```

result is

```
name  type  years  type  color  id
===== ===== ====== ===== ====== ==
Jame    10  2020    10   red     1
Jame    10  2020    10   black   2
Abby    20  2020    20   green   3
Abby    20  2020    20   blue    4
```

but i need only a lower id row not all of them 
like this

```
name  type  years  type  color  id
===== ===== ====== ===== ====== ==
Jame    10  2020    10   red     1
Abby    20  2020    20   green   3
```

what a query command can give me like this result

THX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT c.name, c.type AS c_type, c.years, b.type AS b_type, b.color, b.id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM customer c
    INNER JOIN box b ON c.type = b.type
    WHERE c.years = '2020'
)

SELECT name, c_type, years, b_type, color, id
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: thx for help but i still got error
The column 'type' was specified multiple times for 'cte'.

Comment: @Kloster Apologies, I have fixed it.  Keep in mins that probably most answers given on this site are not fully tested.